# MAGENTO multi-language, how to display a different image in each language-specific header?

Tags: magento, multilingual

I have got a multi-language magento site EN/FR/JP, and want to show a different logo with text like a "free delivery" for each language, just right next to the website name and logo.

I have got these texts with images for each language and have set up static blocks for each language in admin.

**But how can I manage to change a header for each language?**

Answer (score 1):

If you have written text like below than you can do it in translate inline.

```
<?php echo $this->__('Your text'); ?>
```

You can use translate inline by using following menu.

System->configuration->developer->translate inline

enable it for front end. after that refresh page and you find the red border box on every text.click on the icon on red border box it will open box where you can add the language wise text save it.disable translate inline and refresh the cache and page you will see the changed text.